# How to use Nextjs 13.4 fetch Api with Nested Dynamic Routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch-api

I was trying to use Next dynamic route fetching API to get data for my pages dynamically but always getting 404 error on my fetch. What am I doing wrong?
The page is working fine with dynamic routes, but the fetch does not recognize the path to reach the "[pages].js" file.

```
Page: app/application/[page]/[tab] 
Api Fetch: app/api/gantt/[page].js
```

my client side is: (app/application/[page]/[tab]/page.js)

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Page = ({ params }) => {
  const { page, tab } = params;
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/gantt/" + page, {
      method: "GET",
      cache: "no-store",
    }).then((data) => setData(data));
  }, []);
  console.log("data: ", data);

  return <h1>APPLICATION/[PAGE]/[TAB] PAGE</h1>;
};

export default Page;
```

fetch handler:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const { page } = req.query;
  console.log("page: ", page);

  res.status(200).json({ page: page });
}
```

I get this error: "GET [path] 404 (Not Found)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was trying to do it the old way, but I'm using the next app router (13.4), so I need to use route handlers, just create the hierarchy of pages "api/gantt/[page]/route.js". So it get there:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (req, params) => {
  /*
  params is {page: [page name]}
  */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `useEffect` with the `variables` will be changed.
So you can change your `useEffect` like this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/gantt/" + page, {
    method: "GET",
    cache: "no-store",
  }).then((data) => setData(data));
}, [page]);
```

If the 2nd parameter of `useEffect` is `[]`, the 1st parameter - arrow function is executed only once when the component initialized.
But it is like `[variable]`, it is executed every change that variable.

thank you.